# Getting Different value of Datetime.Now.ToLocalTime().Seconds

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().Second it gives second. Problem I have faced is when i run my code on different machine I am getting second value different from each other. for example on my Windows Phone second give : 4 and on my pc second gives : 54 on both side different value.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: `DateTime.Seconds` gives seconds of current instance. Maybe you are running your code in different times (and of course different seconds) on both machines?

Comment: Exactly as @Soner Gönül suggested, first thing would be checking the timezone difference between the devices if any, please report if not, so that I can think of any other reason

Comment: Two separate devices are not (and cannot with normal means) be guaranteed to run with the exact same time. If you try to describe what you're trying to do rather than what you're currently experiencing, we'll have a better chance at helping you. Why do you need them to return the same time?

Comment: Generating secure code which is time based

Comment: @byteboy there is no guarantee the devices will be synced to the second all the time. Usually to do a time based security you need to leave some syncing window. Like a 5 minutes interval.

Comment: FYI - `DateTime.Now` is already the local time.  Calling `ToLocalTime` on it is extraneous.  And if you are really doing something with security, you probably *shouldn't* use the local time, but rather UTC with `DateTime.UtcNow`.